# What is the Arduino code for 433MHz RF TxRx pair connected to one Arduino UNO board to transmit "Hello" text from the transmitter to receive?

Tags: arduino, programming, microprocessor, arduino-uno

I wrote 2 codes but no one shows anything on the Serial Monitor. Please correct my code.

**1ST CODE**

```cpp
#include <RH_ASK.h>

#include <SPI.h>

RH_ASK rf_driver;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    if (!rf_driver.init()) {
        Serial.println("RadioHead initialization failed.");
    }
}

void loop() {
    const char *message_tx = "Hello";
    rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)message_tx, strlen(message_tx));
    rf_driver.waitPacketSent();

    uint8_t buf[RH_ASK_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t buflen = sizeof(buf);
    if (rf_driver.recv(buf, &buflen)) {
        Serial.print("Received: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < buflen; i++) {
            Serial.write(buf[i]);
        }

        Serial.println();
    }

    delay(1000);
}
```

**2ND CODE**

```cpp
#include <VirtualWire.h>

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    vw_setup(2000); // Transmission speed in bits per second

    // Set pins for both transmitter and receiver
    vw_set_tx_pin(12); // Set the transmission pin
    vw_set_rx_pin(11); // Set the receiving pin
    vw_rx_start(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop() {
    const char *message_tx = "Hello";
    vw_send((uint8_t *)message_tx, strlen(message_tx));
    vw_wait_tx(); // Wait for the message to be sent

    uint8_t message_rx[VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t messageLength = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;

    if (vw_get_message(message_rx, &messageLength)) {
        Serial.print("Received: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < messageLength; i++) {
            Serial.write(message_rx[i]); // Print received characters
        }

        Serial.println(); // Print a newline after the message
    }

    delay(1000); // Delay before sending the next message
}
```